# All versions of GCC struggle with default member initializer, that captures this, combined with inherited constructors

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, inheriting-constructors

This story is similar to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43993162/966376). All versions of GCC that support *C++11*, have this exact behaviour. I could not find any other compiler that struggles with my test case.

The test case:

```
struct BaseFooWrapper
{
    BaseFooWrapper(int qux)
    { }
};

struct Foo
{
    Foo(BaseFooWrapper & foo)
        : foo(foo)
    { }

    BaseFooWrapper & foo;
};

struct SomeFooWrapper : public BaseFooWrapper
{
    using BaseFooWrapper::BaseFooWrapper;


    Foo foo{*this};
};

int main()
{
    SomeFooWrapper wrapped_foo(1);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Live on [godbolt.com](https://godbolt.org/g/jQGYGB)

---

This piece of code compiles with **clang** (3.4 through 4.0), **icc** (16, 17), **Visual C++** (19.00.23506).

If I replace constructor inheritance with a hand-written version, then GCC starts to compile the code:

```
struct BaseFooWrapper
{
    BaseFooWrapper(int qux)
    { }
};

struct Foo
{
    Foo(BaseFooWrapper & foo)
        : foo(foo)
    { }

    BaseFooWrapper & foo;
};

struct SomeFooWrapper : public BaseFooWrapper
{
    SomeFooWrapper(int qux)
        : BaseFooWrapper(qux)
    { }


    Foo foo{*this};
};

int main()
{
    SomeFooWrapper wrapped_foo(1);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Live on [godbolt.com](https://godbolt.org/g/bfou2p)

---

Obviously it is not very handy, especially when you have many such classes, and leads to boilerplate code. Basically, the very thing that *inheriting constructors* are designed to fix. This behaviour of GCC renders this great *c++11* feature unavailable in such cases.

So I am really curious whether I am doing something illegal with regard to the standard or this is a bug in GCC?

---

**Edit:**

Filed a [bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80851).

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [Inheriting constructors and brace-or-equal initializers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32525586/inheriting-constructors-and-brace-or-equal-initializers) (as is [Constructor inheritance and direct member initialisation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40932844/constructor-inheritance-and-direct-member-initialisation)) and therefore your bug is a duplicate of the older GCC bug https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67054

Comment: Btw, it doesn't "capture this", as it's not a lambda. It just happens to use `*this` as an expression in the brace-or-equal initialiser. I think that's a red herring and the problem would've occurred regardless of whether or not the argument for said initialiser happened to include `this` in it. Did you test for that?

Comment: @underscore_d, seems that you are correct. Somehow I over-complicated an example.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is not the constructor inheritance, but this line:

```
Foo foo{*this};
```

GCC appears to think it will need a default constructor for struct Foo as well, and since the class has a reference, it is not able to do so.

```
error: no matching function for call to 'Foo::Foo()'
<source>:14:5: note: candidate: Foo::Foo(BaseFooWrapper&)
     Foo(BaseFooWrapper & foo): foo(foo)
     ^~~
<source>:14:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
<source>:10:7: note: candidate: constexpr Foo::Foo(const Foo&)
```

By adding the default constructor it appears to think it needs, then the code compiles:

```
struct Foo
{

    Foo():foo(*new BaseFooWrapper(0))
    {

    }
    Foo(BaseFooWrapper & foo): foo(foo)
    { 

    }

    BaseFooWrapper & foo;
};
```

It does look like a bug.

Comment: Unfortunately, adding default constructor is not an option at all.

Comment: I know I just wanted to illustrate where gcc is getting it wrong

Comment: @GreenScape So please file a bug to get this fixed in GCC for yourself and everyone else.

Answer (score 2):

I could be wrong, but quoting from the n4527 draft standard in **[class.this]**:

> In the body of a non-static (9.3) member function, the keyword this is a prvalue expression whose value
>   is the address of the object for which the function is called. The type of this in a member function of
>   a class X is X*.

In the OP's code, the initialisation of `SomeFooWrapper::foo` is not taking place in a member function. Therefore the keyword `this` has no reasonable meaning as far as the standard is concerned.

Or have I missed something?

Comment: Actually, ititialisation does take place in the member function: `SomeFooWrapper::SomeFooWrapper(int)`. I mean should, according to standard, not in this case, with regard to GCC.